# Rails: How to make input read only depending on value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a nested model form, my `Foo` has many `Bars` and `Baz` has many `Bars`

**Foo.rb**

```
has_many :bars
accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
```

**Bar.rb**

```
belongs_to :Foo
belongs_to :Baz
```

**Baz.rb**

```
has_many :bars
```

**views/foos/_form.html.haml**

```
= f.simple_fields_for :bars do |p|
   = render "bar_fields", f: p
```

When I bring up the form to edit, I would like to disable the editing of a particular `Bar` if it belongs to a certain `Baz`.

For each of the `bars` that it renders, how do I check within the view, what the value is of a certain attribute. In this case, what the value of `Baz` is in the `Bar` record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views/foos/_form.html.haml

```
= f.simple_fields_for :bars, @foo.bars.not_belonging_to_a_certain_baz(baz_id) do |p|
   = render "bar_fields", f: p
```

Bar.rb

```
scope :not_belonging_to_a_certain_baz, ->{ |baz_id| where("bars.baz_id != ?", baz_id) }
```

Or if you are not able to use scope, you can check each bar separatly when render bar_fields partial:

views/foos/_form.html.haml

```
= f.simple_fields_for :bars, do |p|
   = render "bar_fields", f: p if p.object.baz_id != baz_id
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but I will want to let users see the data even though they cant edit it. any thoughts on that?

Comment: The second part of my answer is what you want. You can always get current Bar by calling #object method of the form object. Within the bar_fields partial current Bar is f.object. The Baz of the current Bar is f.object.baz

Comment: tried but all it is doing is not rendering the nested model. I'd still like to view it but just not editable. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I found something similar and here's what I did

**_form.html.haml**

```
= f.simple_fields_for :bars do |p|
    - if f.object.baz_id == baz_id
        = render "bar_fields", f: p
    - else
        = render "bar_fields_readonly", f: p
```

Comment: You did this using my solution. The main point of the solution is to use #object method to get what you want. Why don't you mark my answer as correct ?